# How to display a DataBound Pushpin on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am trying to create a pushpin on Windows Phone that shows a number of locations, including there name, rating and more. I have searched MSDN, Stack Overflow and other sites for a solution to this and found only partial answers.

This is my current attempt. It doesn't work at all. It does create a pushpin, but it is not changed to show a grid or any of the other elements. Instead it shows a blank pushpin in the top left of the map.

```
<mi:Map x:Name="map" Margin="-12,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" CredentialsProvider="Something else goes here :)">
   <mi:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
      <mi:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <mi:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}">
               <Grid Background="{Binding Background}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="6,0"/>
                  <ProgressBar Maximum="5" Value="{Binding Rating}"/>
               </Grid>
             </mi:Pushpin>
          </DataTemplate>
       </mi:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </mi:MapItemsControl>
 </mi:Map>
```

How can I get the above code or something like it to work?

My previous solution involved creating the elements with code, the problem with that is that it got messy beyond a few pins and could not easily be used to get other information (such as a Stores URL).

Edit:
Some extra information on the code behind everything.

```
public struct PushpinModel
{
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public float Rating { get; set; }
    public Brush Background { get; set; }
}
```

These pushpin models are added to the Pushpin's observable collection with the AddPin method:

```
public void AddPin(GeoCoordinate coord, string Title, string url, float rating, Brush background)
{
    Pushpins.Add(new PushpinModel { Location = coord, Name = Title, Rating = rating, Url = url, Background = background} );
}
```

My GeoCoordinateWatcher calls the watcher_PositionChanged event when it's position is changed. This adds a pushpin at the users location.

Currently the ZoomToUser() function is being called, but the pushpin is not appearing.

Comment: Everything looks good except.... what is Pushpins? odds are you meant to put {Binding Pushpoins}

Comment: Pushpins is an ObservableCollection of my PushpinModel class, it stores has members for all the stuff you see later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong

```
 <mi:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="Pushpins">
```

if it is a property of the datacontext it should be

```
 <mi:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
```

Comment: changing to what you have above gets rid of the Pushpin in the top left, but it does not show the Grid, TextBlock or Progress Bar. In fact it doesn't show anything. Do you have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Ah, I fixed it. My ItemsSource as you mentioned above was not working. Setting it in code worked fine.